# How can I use html5 to input a local file and output the file on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, io

I'm trying to get a grip on the file API in HTML5 for accessing local files in a browser. I found some other SO questions about this and even found a nice guide [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) for choosing files locally.

However, I really need to be able to access text files this way and print them on screen, like in a textarea element. Does anyone know how this is done? As an example, I would like to read in a flat text file with a single line of text and print the contents in a textarea.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If requesting to close the question, please provide some kind of input so that I can understand what is wrong with my coding question!

Comment: I didn't vote to close the question, but this is the reason given for the first close vote: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: Questions have to "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" meaning you need to show what you've tried so far.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Got it, I'll edit my question with code snippets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Any Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        if (!files.length) {
          alert('Please select a file!');
          return;
        }

        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                document.getElementById('output').textContent = evt.target.result;
            }  
        };
        reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    }


document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the tutorial you mentioned but when you read a text file use `FileReader.readAsText` to read the file as a text instead of as binary and then store that text as the value of a text area form element.

If you have trouble getting this to work, post a question with your actual code attempt and what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the FILE API:

For example:

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>Select a File to open:</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
    <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button><td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript:

```
function loadFileAsText()
{
var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
{
    var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
};
fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```